# How do I send data into an Angular component only once (since @Input listens for updates all the time)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-services

I have an Angular Scroller component

```html
<app-scroller></app-scroller>
```

that provides a skeleton for displaying an array of images

#### Random Component

```html
<app-scroller [init]="getImages('cats')"></app-scroller>
<app-scroller [init]="getImages('dogs')"></app-scroller>
```

```js
getImages(src: string) {
  //THIS FUNCTION GETS CALLED AGAIN AND AGAIN
  return {
    aspect: '16/9',
    res: 'min',
    sources: this.imageService.getImagesFromAPI(src)
  };
}
```

#### Scroller Component

```js
public movies: string[] = [];
@Input() init: {aspect: string, res: string, sources: Promise<string[]>};

ngOnInit() {
  this.init.sources.then(images => this.movies = movies);
}
```

but this results in the the `getImages` and therefore the `sources` Promise to be executed over and over

Is there a way I can send data to the Scroller component only once (therefore without using `@Input()` )

Comment: It's hard to diagnose and offer a solution with just three tiny bits of code. Please provide the complete picture, if possible a minimal reproductible example

Comment: Is my edit a bit more clear now?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to call your service once to get the array of images and save it inside your component as a property,

something like this

```
myService.getData.subscribe(data=> this.catImages = data)
```

Comment: In the Component using the Scroller or the Scroller component?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question and setup correctly, you are asking about preventing an `@Input` from listening, what if you instead prevent data from emitting to this input?

You could deliver an observable stream that emits just once, eg.

```
catImages$ = this.catDataFromService$.pipe(
  take(1),
)

<app-scroller [source]="catImages$ | async"></app-scroller>
```

Alternatively, you could construct your own Observable and complete it when necessary.

Comment: I am using @Input only because I don't have another solution.  The Scroller component expects an image source and handles the data from there. I just need a way to send the source to the Scroller Component from another component  only a single time

Comment: This is exactly what I am talking about: define the stream in the container (parent) and send it down to the scroller's input using the async pipe

Answer (score 0):

Use property binding only to send the category id (dogs/cats) to the component and call getImages(cateogryID) only once in the child component.

Parent component

```
<app-scroller [categoryId]="catIdProperty"></app-scroller>
```

Child component:

```
@input()
categoryId: string;

images: [type here] = [initialization here];


ngOnInit(): void {

  this.images = this.getImages(categoryId); // Btw, could getImages() reside in the imageService?

}
```